# Remove double file contents

Tags: python, file

I have previously written a file in python and I wrote the same contents twice while trying to run the script for the second time.

Here is my file content:

> Story1: A short story is a piece of prose fiction that typically can be read in one sitting and focuses on a self-contained incident or series of linked incidents, with the intent of evoking a "single effect" or mood, however there are many exceptions to this. A dictionary definition is "an invented prose narrative shorter than a novel usually dealing with a few characters and aiming at unity of effect and often concentrating on the creation of mood rather than plot. Story1: A short story is a piece of prose fiction that typically can be read in one sitting and focuses on a self-contained incident or series of linked incidents, with the intent of evoking a "single effect" or mood, however there are many exceptions to this. A dictionary definition is "an invented prose narrative shorter than a novel usually dealing with a few characters and aiming at unity of effect and often concentrating on the creation of mood rather than plot.

I am using python Set operator like this, but this won't work for my case:

```
uniqlines = set(open('file.txt').readlines())
bar = open('file', 'w').writelines(set(uniqlines))
```

In my case, there are now newline characters so everything is read once. I want to be able to delete the contents after the Story1: is encountered the second time. 
How do I accomplish it?

Comment: Can't you just open the file in a text editor and remove the second part?

Comment: I have many files in many folders. I am using glob.glob() to iterate over all files and do the stuffs. So I wont be able to do it manually.

Comment: You could take the first 20 (or less or more, depending of your your content) chars from the file and read until your encounter again those 20 chars.

Comment: And in each file there is `Story1: <some text> Story1: <some text>`? Or do different files have something else than `Story1:` as separator?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update:** Since you don't have line breaks to split up the file, you're likely better off just slurping the file, splitting appropriately, and writing a new file. Simple solution would be:

```
import os, tempfile

with open('file.txt') as f,\
     tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile('w', dir='.', delete=False) as tf:
    # You've got a space only before second copy, so it's a useful partition point
    firstcopy, _, _ f.read().partition(' Story1: ')
    # Write first copy
    tf.write(firstcopy)
# Exiting with block closes temporary file so data is there
# Atomically replace original file with rewritten temporary file
os.replace(tf.name, 'file.txt')
```

Technically, this isn't *completely* safe against actual power loss, since data might not be written to disk before the `replace` metadata update occurs. If you're paranoid, tweak it to explicitly block until the data is synced by adding the following two lines just before dedenting out of the `with` block (after the `write`):

```
    tf.flush()  # Flushes Python level buffers to OS
    os.fsync(tf.fileno())  # Flush OS kernel buffer out to disk, block until done
```

---

**Old answer for case where copies begin on separate lines:**

Find where the second copy begins, and truncate the file:

```
seen_story1 = False
with open('file.txt', 'r+') as f:
    while True:
        pos = f.tell() # Record position before next line

        line = f.readline()
        if not line:
            break  # Hit EOF

        if line.startswith('Story1:'):
            if seen_story1:
                # Seen it already, we're in duplicate territory
                f.seek(pos)   # Go back to end of last line
                f.truncate()  # Truncate file
                break         # We're done
            else:
                seen_story1 = True  # Seeing it for the first time
```

Since all you're doing is removing duplicate information from the end of the file, this is safe and effective; `truncate` should be atomic on most OSes, so the trailing data is freed all at once, with no risk of partial write corruption or the like.

Comment: Apparently the whole file consists of a single line, so iterating over the lines won't work.

Comment: @mkrieger1: Ah, whoops. I thought the second copy was on a separate line, clearly misread. Will fix.

Comment: Here's an idea: Just truncate the file in the middle, assuming it consists of two copies of the same text.

Comment: @ShadowRanger: I get this error `OSError: telling position disabled by next() call`

Comment: @TranquilOshan: Ugh... That's just dumb. It's fixable by using a different means of reading the lines, but it's ridiculous that they differentiated iteration from simple `readline` calls (and AFAICT, didn't document this at all). Fixed.

Comment: @mkrieger1: Possible, but it looks like it might not be *exactly* the same. There is a random space before the second `Story1:`, which might mean the halfway point isn't where we think. You'd have to do the work in binary mode (you can't seek a text file to "the middle", only to the beginning, end, or a position saved from a call to `tell`), and if there is some small off-by-one error from the space, you might end up truncating in the middle of a UTF-8 character's encoding (granted, in this case, it looks ASCII, but best not to assume).

Answer (score 1):

You could use the find method.

```
# set the word you want to look for
myword = "Story1"

#read the file into a variable called text
with open('file.txt', 'r+') as fin:
    text = fin.read()

#find your word for the first time. This method returns  the lowest index of the substring if it is found.
# That's why we add the length of the word we are looking for.
index_first_time_found = text.find(myword) + len(myword)

# We search again, but now we start looking from the index of our previous result.
index_second_time_found = text.find(myword, index_first_time_found)

# We cut of everything upto the index of our second index.
new_text = text[:index_second_time_found]

print(new_text)
```

Comment: After doing all the codes in the same with loop and writing `f.seek(0) `before writing out to file and `f.truncate()` after `fin.write()`, I am able to do the required task.